# Regarding assigning task to daemon thread

Tags: java, threadpool, daemon

I have one requirement that I want to create a pool of 5 threads and now I want to make 1 thread out of those 5 threads as a `daemon` thread and when that particular 1 thread becomes as daemon thread , then I want to assign some task to that daemon thread related to any service such that when the java program exits I can check in window task manager that particular daemon thread is still doing that task., Please advise how to achieve that ..! As I am stuck up on this..!

below is my code...

```
public class StoppingThread extends Thread //extend thread class 
{
    // public  synchronized void run()
     //synchronized (this)

    private volatile boolean Completed = false;


    public void setCompleted() {
        Completed = true;
    }


    public void run()
    {
      for(int i=0;i<20 && !Completed;++i) {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);

          System.out.print(i +"\n"+ "..");
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } 
    } 

 public static void main(String... a) 
 {
     StoppingThread x = new StoppingThread();
     StoppingThread y = new StoppingThread();
     x.start();
     x.setName("first");
     x.setCompleted(); // Will complete as soon as the latest iteration finishes means bolean variable value is set to true 
     y.start();
     y.setName("second");

     }  

 }
```

Now in this I want to make Y thread as daemon thread and then want to assign some task to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ShutDownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html). The Thread which you register into the hook will be called when the application ends. You can add all clean up codes(DB,Stream,Context etc..) or any custom feature in this thread run method.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { // clean up code like closing streams,DB etc }
});
```

Comment: @Akhil..could you please make modification in my above code..! as per your suggestion that will be a great help in understanding the concept

Comment: let me quote you "when the java program exits I can check in window task manager that particular daemon thread is still doing that task" . can you elaborate ?? A daemon thread will exit if there is no other threads running.so what exactly you want this thread to do ?